# UIPanGesture and UISwipeGesture in the same view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have a `UIView` that already has a `UIPanGesture` implemented that works when a user drags the `UIView` half way up causing some action.  As of now, it works just fine. Now, within the same `UIView` I want to implement a a `UISwipeGesture` so when the user swipes up, some other method would be called.  I've been reading about the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods and I'm thinking I need to use `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` but I'm not sure.

I implemented the following in my viewDidLoad and got an error saying "invalid argument.  Unrecognized selector sent to instance"

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * panRec = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePan:)];
panRec.delegate = self;
[panedView addGestureRecognizer:panRec];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeRec = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
swipeRec.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
swipeRec.delegate=self;
[panedView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRec];

[self gestureRecognizer:swipeRec shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer: panRec];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:` is a delegate of the the UIGestureRecognizer.  Meaning , you will implement the method , and when a gesture happens this method will be called automatically . To enable the gesture recognisers calling this method you need to set the gesture recogniser delegate to self, this can be done in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I tried implementing what you said, but couldn't get it to work.  I added my code above with the error I'm getting.

Comment: You are calling the method `shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer` on the object of self. Implement meaning you declare the method in you class . Just copy this - `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{       }` and paste this method in your class. And you can write your login in the curly brackets. And remove that line `[self gestureRecognizer:swipeRec shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer: panRec];`

Comment: Can you clarify what should go in the curly brackets?  I copied this into my class `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{       }` and I removed `[self gestureRecognizer:swipeRec shouldRequireFailureOfGestureRecognizer: panRec];`

Comment: Hmmm so you need both gesture recognisers to work simultaneously right ? instead of using the above gesture recogniser delegate you can implement this instead `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{ return YES; }` - Replace the previous method with this.